# How to add fog effect to Mapbox on iOS

Tags: mapbox-gl, drawrect, fog, mapbox-ios

I don't have a 10 reputation to post images.

[Effect picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaV9R.jpg)

The map is covered by fog, and the map is displayed where you walk, that is, the coordinates are collected according to where you walk, and the fog is not displayed

use view -drawRect ，bad effect